# unique css for a logged in customer?

Tags: css

On our website some customers see additional text when they are logged in. The css "hides" this if they are not this customer but the gaps are still showing. You can see an example here

The styling currently that displays this block is

```
.item {
width:150px;
margin-right:30px;    
height: 380px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
display: block;
float: left;
```

}

For these non customers I want it to be

```
.item {
width:150px;
margin-right:30px;    
height: 350px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
display: block;
float: left;
```

}

Within another .cs file this block of code pulls in the pricing

```
 // handle non-discounted customerLevel cases
        if (ThisCustomer.CustomerLevelID == 0 || (ThisCustomer.LevelDiscountPct == 0 && extPrice      == 0))
        {
            if (ThisCustomer.CustomerLevelID == 0 && AppLogic.AppConfigBool("WholesaleOnlySite"))  // wholesale site with default customerLevel
            {
                results.Append("&nbsp;");
            }
            else  // show Level 0 Pricing
            {
                if (salePrice == 0 || ThisCustomer.CustomerLevelID > 0)
                {
                    results.Append("<span class=\"variantprice\">" + genericPriceLabel + regularPriceFormatted + "</span>");
                }
                else
                {
                    results.Append("<span class=\"RegularPrice\" >" + regularPriceLabel + regularPriceFormatted + "</span><br />");
                    results.Append("<span class=\"SalePrice\" style=\"color: " + AppLogic.AppConfig("OnSaleForTextColor") + "\">" + salePriceLabel + discountedPriceFormatted + "</span>");
                }

                results.Append("&nbsp;");

                results.Append(taxSuffix);
            }
        }
```

Is there any way to incorporate css into a cs file so that if the CustomerLevelID is zero it will only display the height at 350px?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cascading:

```
.item {
    width:150px;
    margin-right:30px;    
    height: 350px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    float: left;

}
.loggedin .item {
    height: 380px;
}
```

Then in the resulting code add class `loggedin` to the `body` tag during rendering if there's an active login, like `<body class="loggedin">`.